# why does brain produces noise?

Tags: brain

when i look at a white wall i see little colored dots moving in circles filling my whole visual view, just like the static on a tv but then in color. 
I thought everybody had this but recently i discovered it is not normal ?

furthermore i see something which looks like tiny cells, just like you look under a microscope and bright white dots which are moving from the top of my view to the bottom. it is always present but some days more than others.

when it i see it more it is sometime together with a high pitched noise for a few seconds or a weird in my head like you have a beer or 2.

I cannot remember a time in which I did not have this (now 24 years).

I would like to know why the brain produces this noise ? it is not helping me to "survive" so why does it do this ? and what parts of he brain are involved in this ?

Comment: @rg255 nope thats totally not it, thats why i asked it seperately

Comment: I think you mean [muscae volitantes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater) Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything for your first ("i see little colored dots moving in circles filling my whole visual view") and third ("it is sometime together with a high pitched noise for a few seconds") questions.

Comment: it explains what the "tiny cells" and "bright white dots" are. Note: "*it is not helping me to "survive" so why does it do this*" - not everything is adaptive.